# PHP - If... statement to insert collapsible div where a particular string is found

Tags: php, css

I have a list of image URLs stored in a database, separated by line breaks. The following PHP code displays them on my site:

```
$images = explode("\n", $value );

$value = '';
foreach ($images as $im){
    $value .= '<img src="'. $im . '" style="max-width:1024px"/> <br />';
}
```

However, I want to hide some of the images behind a collapsible div if they contain a particular string.
Is it possible to write an if statement so $value changes to some HTML code displaying a collapsible div?

For example:

Rather than $value:

```
<img src="'. www.example.com/hiddenimage1.jpg  . '" style="max-width:1024px"/> <br />
```

It would become:

```
<div class="collapsiblediv" style="etc etc"><img src="'. www.example.com/hiddenimage1.jpg  . '" style="max-width:1024px"/> <br /></div>
```

However anything NOT containing "hiddenimage" would display as usual.

Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is very possible. Please do show your attempt

Comment: Side note: "I have a list of image URLs stored in a database, separated by line breaks." is bad design. You should look into refactoring this so that another table holds individual links.

Comment: Akintunde-Rotimi The "foreach" part confuses me...Not sure where to put my "if".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strstr()` function of PHP to search for a chunk of a string within a string.

Using this function, you can search for the value 'hiddenimage' within your `foreach` loop. Based on a conditional, you could then return either the collapsible `<div>` or the `<img>`

You could try this code

```
$images = explode("\n", $value );
$value = '';
foreach ($images as $im){
  if(strstr( $im, 'hiddenimage' ) {
    <div class="collapsiblediv" style="etc etc"><img src="'. 
    $im  . '" style="max-width:1024px"/> <br 
    /></div>
  } else {
    $value .= '<img src="'. $im . '" style="max-width:1024px"/> <br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I just came up with something similar, but it wasn't working. I will give yours a try! Thank you so much.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Just take note that `strstr` is case sensitive. There's a case insensitive version `stristr` in case you ever need it.